# PHP Child class accessing Parent variable

Tags: php, oop

I'm a newbie that needs help. I'm trying to get the parent value, but I'm failing at that. Helpful comments are much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
abstract class mainClass 
{
  protected $cost=0;
  public $set=false;
  function setCost($cost){
    $this->cost;
  }
  function getCost()
  {
    return $this->cost;
  }
}

class supplierClass extends  mainClass { }

class branchClass extends  supplierClass 
{
  function setCost  ($cost)
  {
    if( $cost==0)
    {
      parent::getCost();
        $cost=$this->cost;
    }
    return$this->cost=$cost;
  }
}
```

db loops though supplier branch buy/sell transactions

```
while ($rs=$pdoUpdate->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
{
  //$rs->current='35' transferring from supplier 35
  //$rs->cost=$50.00
  //$rs->isTo='27' to branch 27
  // several branches/suppliers transactions

  if(!isset($supplier[$rs->current]->set))
  {
    $supplier[$rs->current]=new supplierClass();
    $supplier[$rs->current]->set=true;
  }
  if(!isset($branch[$rs->isTo]->set))
  {
    $branch[$rs->isTo]=new branchClass();
    $branch[$rs->isTo]->set=true;
  }
  $supplier[$rs->current]->setCost($rs->cost);
  $branch[$rs->isTo]->setCost(0);
}
echo "branch price=". $branch[$rs->isTo]->getCost();
// branch price=0
```

But I want it to default to the suppliers cost of $50!

Sorry if this is totally incorrect but this is new to me 
many thanks. T hope that I'll be learning from you.

Comment: That's nice, but what is your question?

Comment: You're working with instances, and there is no relationship between individual instances of branchClass and supplierClass.... setting a supplier instance's cost to 50 doesn't mean that parent::cost in a branch instance will be affected in any way, because ever instance's property values are unique to that instance

Comment: If i understand the meaning of the function/class/db-id names correctly, i assume you want to have an default price and that price should be overwritten by a specific supplier price if set?

Comment: noreabu yes i would like to pass a default price thru if need be; Machavity can i pass values form one instance to the next then (top down)

Comment: I fixed some major formatting of the code sections and some grammar which should make the question much more comprehensible. Please avoid 'TAB's in the future as suggested by SO, because they make formatting your code much more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

**At first**

**$supplier[$rs->current]** and **$branch[$rs->isTo]** - **these are two different objects**.

For this example objects **A** and **B** (**$supplier[$rs->current]** and **$branch[$rs->isTo]**)

This code: **$supplier[$rs->current]->setCost($rs->cost)**; - set *cost* in object **A**.

This code: **$branch[$rs->isTo]->setCost(0);** - set *cost* in object **B**
But **B** do not know about the class **A**, because of this, cost (object B) = 0

**In the second**

Code: 
**parent::getCost();** - returns the value(*cost*) of the object "**B**". This does not need to call.

Next line further you are using an attribute (*cost* of the object "**B**") without using the method.

You can do this:

```
function setCost  ($cost)
{
    if( $cost==0)
    {
        $this->cost = $this->getCost();
    }
    return $this->cost;
}
```

**Thirdly**

For solutions to your problem - you need to use one object.

How to do this - it depends on the overall tasks and resources.

As an example I can offer this solution:

```
class Cost
{
   protected $cost = 0;
   function setCost($cost){
       $this->cost;
   }
   function getCost()
   {
       return $this->cost;
   }
}

abstract class mainClass 
{
  public $set=false;
  public $cost;
  function __construct(Cost $cost)
  {
       $this->cost = $cost;
  }
  function getCost()
  {
    return $this->cost->getCost();
  }

  function setCost  ($cost)
  {
    $this->cost->setCost($cost);
  }
}

class supplierClass extends  mainClass { }

class branchClass extends  supplierClass 
{
  function setCost  ($cost)
  {
    if($cost==0)
    {
        $cost=$this->cost->getCost();
    }
    $this->cost->setCost($cost);
  }
}
```

**OR use static class**

```
class Cost
{
   protected static $cost = 0;
   function static setCost($cost){
       static::$cost;
   }
   function static getCost()
   {
       static::$cost;
   }
}

abstract class mainClass 
{
  public $set=false;
  function getCost()
  {
    return Cost::getCost();
  }

  function setCost  ($cost)
  {
    Cost::setCost($cost);
  }
}

class supplierClass extends  mainClass { }

class branchClass extends  supplierClass 
{
  function setCost  ($cost)
  {
    if($cost==0)
    {
        $cost=Cost::getCost();
    }
    Cost::setCost($cost);
  }
}
```